# Atom: how to disable the "telescope" project section ("your project is currently empty")?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

I have removed the telemetry consent but the window with the telescope on which "your project is currently empty" is still there.

How can I disable it?

Is there any package which removes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse the whole tree-view panel by: hover you cursor over the inner edge of the panel and a semi-circle with left arrow will appear in the middle; click that.

If you just want a blank tree-view panel instead (hide the graphic & buttons), you can add this to your [stylesheet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks):

```
#add-projects-view {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The panel with the telescope and the phrase "Your project is currently empty" is shown not by Atom itself, but by a package "tree-view". This issue is supposed to be fixed in version "v0.229.0" of the package. Meanwhile, you can just disable the package to get rid of the panel:

1. Open preferences: Edit > Preferences (Linux), Atom > Preferences (macOS), or File > Settings (Windows).
2. Select "Packages".
3. Search for "tree-view"
4. Click "Disable"

Comment: God Bless You my friend, you save the OCD nation. This was nagging me for eons.